# What does the word 「いってえ」 mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language

Below here is a full sentence I have found the word.

> この品物の山は**いってえ**どうしたことだ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「いってえ」 is how the "tough Kanto guy" would colloquially pronounce 「[一体]{いったい}」.

「一体」, when combined with a question word (in this case, どう), is the Japanese equivalent of "on earth", "the heck", "the f***", etc.

「この[品物]{しなもの}の[山]{やま}はいってえどうしたことだ。」 = "How on earth did you get all this mountain of stuff?"

Depending on the context, there may be a better translation.

Comment: +1 for "tough Kanto guy" :)

Comment: Is the「ことだ」 used as interrogative particle?